# How do you remove portrait background with Depth Api?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I was watching the Image Editing with Depth WWDC video from 2017 ([link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/508/?time=1325)), where they take the background of a portrait mode and make it black. They also showed some code but I'm not sure how to use it. Could anyone provide some sample code?

Portrait Image with Black Background:
[image]
Code:
[image]

Comment: Does this Q&A help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506934/how-to-capture-depth-data-from-camera-in-ios-11-and-swift-4

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is change:

```
vec4 result = vec4(imageColor.rgb * scaleFactor, imageColor.a);
```

to:

```
if disparity < cutoff {
    vec4 result = vec4(imageColor.rgb, 0);
}
```

where cutoff is the disparity(depth) that you want to stop showing.

I've been working with AVDepthData, but am not experienced with filters.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Stephen, thank you for the answer. The issue is I just don't know how you use this code:

kernel vec4 into_darkness(__sample imageColor, __sample normalizedDisparity, float power) {}