# Get real size of someone's face

Tags: ios, opencv

I am developing an iOS app where I want to get the size of user's real face so that I can suggest him/her suitable (matched) sized glasses.

I have detected user's face using **OpenCV** and got various dimensions of *eyes, nose, face,* etc.

But I want the real size from that dimensions (i.e in **millimetres** that I am getting in pixels).

I have searched a lot but could not get any solution matching with my requirement.

Has anyone idea how to calculate real size (i.e in millimetres) of the someone's face?

Thank you.

Comment: What should happen if someone presents a 50% scale model of their face to the camera? How do you tell?

Comment: wouldn't ARKit be easier for this task?

Comment: @JohnDvorak That I can make sure that 100% face present in the camera. That we can achieve.

Comment: @Scriptable ARKit can get the topology and dimensions of face, but I am trying to get Real life length of the face.

Comment: There are ARKit apps that can measure rooms and stuff. see if you can find out how they do it. it is an interesting question, i would like to know the answer myself but I think it may be too broad for SO

Comment: Have the user present an object of known dimensions (like a coin) then compute the difference between this known size and the other elements in the picture.

Comment: @Scriptable yes, its is possible using ARKit to measure rooms and stuffs, but not for front camera. I want same for front camera.

Comment: I wonder to what extent a human iris is of known size. Google cites 10.2 to 13 mm, so not great.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two ways of doing it.

1. You have an object of *known size* in the image that you can use to compare with. That object must also be at the same (or known) distance from the camera as the face.
2. If the camera supports depth, you can get the distance to the face from the camera, and using that to calculate the actual size of the face. This option is currently only available on iPhone X. The accuracy of the depth data can vary, so I am not sure how well it might work for you.

[Read more about capturing depth data here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45092986/4543629)

[Read more on depth data accuracy here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdataaccuracy?language=objc)

Comment: Any idea about a demo or such that demonstrates the front camera of iphoneX using depth?

Comment: I recommend watching the WWDC video that talks about this. They also present a sample app. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/

Answer (score 1):

If you have no reference point for size in the image, i guess there is really no way to tell the exact size. You would need at least one length that correlates to your picture to get some sort of a result.

That said, this would only work a 100% accurately on images of plain objects, because objects further away seem to be smaller in an image (like, e.g. [here](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-miniature-of-the-eiffel-tower-with-the-real-eiffel-tower-background-48300081.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=003E45CC-AA24-4077-BD4D-CC6B2C524648&p=102532&n=0&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26pn%3D1%26ps%3D100%26sortby%3D2%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26npgs%3D0%26qt%3Dfrance%2520miniature%26qt_raw%3Dfrance%2520miniature%26lic%3D3%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26ot%3D0%26creative%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26pc%3D%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26tbar%3D1%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26archive%3D1%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26a%3D%26cdid%3D%26cdsrt%3D%26name%3D%26qn%3D%26apalib%3D%26apalic%3D%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26xstx%3D0%26simid%3D%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26nu%3D%26t%3D%26edoptin%3D%26customgeoip%3D%26cap%3D1%26cbstore%3D1%26vd%3D0%26lb%3D%26fi%3D2%26edrf%3D%26ispremium%3D1)).
You would need multiple pictures from different sides (all with a size reference) and there would be a horrendous amount of calculations to do.

The focal length of the camera will distort your image as well, making accurate measurement even harder (see [comparision of different focal lengths with different distances to the face](https://bakerdh.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/allsmall.jpg)).