# Getting depth data from custom camera

Tags: swift, camera, ios11, iphone-x

I've followed [Capturing Photos with Depth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth) and went through every suggestion in [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506934/how-to-capture-depth-data-from-camera-in-ios-11-and-swift-4), however, I'm not able to get any depth data from my custom camera. Here's my latest edit on the code, do you have any idea about this issue?

when I tap the camera button, I get:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I've reviewed the solutions for that too. They're mostly related to the segue, but I double checked this part of code and storyboard and it seems fine. (I didn't have any issue before adding depth to the code!)

```
class CameraViewController : UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!

  var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
  var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
  var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
  var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

  var image: UIImage?

  var depthDataMap: CVPixelBuffer?
  var depthData: AVDepthData?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupDevice()
    setupIO()
    setupPreviewLayer()
    startRunningCaptureSession()
  }

  func setupDevice() {
    self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
  }

  func setupIO() {
    guard let captureInputDevice = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.captureDevice!),
      self.captureSession.canAddInput(captureInputDevice)
      else { fatalError("Can't add video input.") }
    self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    self.captureSession.addInput(captureInputDevice)

    self.photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    self.photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
    guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput!)
      else { fatalError("Can't add photo output.") }
    self.captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
    self.captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
    self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
  }

  func setupPreviewLayer() {
    self.cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
    self.cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)             
  }
  func startRunningCaptureSession() {
    self.captureSession.startRunning()
  }

  @IBAction func cameraButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any) {    
    let setting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc])
    setting.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = self.photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
    self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: setting, delegate: self)
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPhoto" {
      let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
      let previewVC = nav.topViewController as! PhotoViewController

      previewVC.image = self.image
      previewVC.depthData = self.depthData
      previewVC.depthDataMap = self.depthDataMap
    }
  }
}

extension CameraViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
  func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
      image = UIImage(data: imageData)
      let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)
      let auxiliaryData = CGImageSourceCopyAuxiliaryDataInfoAtIndex(imageSource!, 0, kCGImageAuxiliaryDataTypeDisparity) as? [AnyHashable: Any]

      let depthData = try? AVDepthData(fromDictionaryRepresentation: auxiliaryData!)
      self.depthDataMap = depthData?.depthDataMap

      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto", sender: self)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the problem with my code:](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109135)

DepthDataDelivery won't be supported unless the photo output is added to a session and the input to the session is properly configured to deliver depth.

1. Set the session preset first:

   self.captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
2. After adding dual camera input, add the photo output.

   guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput!)
3. Now set depth delivery enabled:

   self.photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput!.isDepthDataDeliverySupported